# How to get .Top(5) when using non-generic EF db.Set(type)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

How do I make this happen ?

```
public object[] GetFiveObjects(Type mytype){

    var db = new MyContext();
    return db.Set(mytype). ->Take(5) ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var db = new MyContext();
return db.Set(mytype).OfType<object>().Take(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why non-generic...
Or am I missing some point ?

Something like that is quite straightforward and simple :

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetFirstFive<T>() where T : EntityObject
{
    Entities dbContext = new Entities();
    return dbContext.CreateObjectSet<T>.Take(5);
}
```

That way, you can get the first five entities of any entity you want.

Anyway, good questions lead to better answers.

Comment: Well, I asked the question this way for a reason. 
If it would be possible to use <T> in my situation, this question wouldn't be here, right ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use `.Cast<object>()`, i.e:

```
public object[] GetFiveObjects(Type mytype){

    var db = new MyContext();
    return db.Set(mytype).Cast<object>().Take(5).ToArray();
}
```